How do you get yout website source code from AWS?
I hosted a site on AWS without Github on the free hosting. I just dragged and dropped the source code into AWS and hooked up the domain. I now need to update the source code so I can re-upload it.
Is there a way to get to the source code when you host without a git partner?
